# Best way to using mysqli object in class

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my code in config.php file:

```
    <?php
$db_username =  'name';
$db_password = 'my password';
$db_name = 'my db';
$db_host = 'localhost';
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        throw new Exception("Error in Database Connection!");
    }
?>
```

Now I have separate function.php with class commonFunctions

```
<?php
require_once '../config/config.php';
class commonFunctions {
function doLogin(){
global $mysqli;
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE itemcolor = 'red'") ;
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
return $row_cnt;
}
}
$common=new commonFunctions();
?>
```

Here I am using `global $mysqli;` to access $mysqli from config, which may not be a appropriate way to program and using `global $mysqli;` in every function to access $mysqli looks so bad.
Can you guys pls suggest better and clean way.
Thanks

Comment: You should start by fixing the error (missing `'` in the first example).

Comment: fixed it Sverri now waiting for your positive response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what programming paradigm you're comfortable with. Personally I like my PHP to be Object Orientated (OO), so i'd put the mysql in a new class called DB or something and then when I want to run the query i'd do `$db->query('blabla')`.

```
class DB {

    private $db;

    function __construct() {
        $dbConfig = Main::app()->config['db'];
        $this->db = new \mysqli($dbConfig['host'], $dbConfig['user'], $dbConfig['pass'], $dbConfig['db']);
    }

    public function query($query, $where = false) {
        if (!empty($where)) {
            if (strpos(strtolower($where), 'where') > 0)
                $query .= ' ' . $where;
            else
                $query .= ' WHERE ' . $where;
        }
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        if (!isset($result) || $result ===  false) {
            dd([$query, $this->db->error, $where]);
        }
        /* will return true on INSERT / UPDATE queries */
        if ($result !== true)
            return  $result->fetch_all(MYSQL_ASSOC);
    }


}
```

Maybe you might just want to create a function in commonFunctions that handled all queries?

```
 function query($query) {
     global $mysqli;
      return $mysqli->query($query);;
    }
```